# Android Studio: It is possible to graph your score(graph view) after taking quiz?

Tags: android-studio

i would like to ask about how to graph your score in android studio after taking the quiz because i want to add a legend in my application where the user can see his/her progress.. any source would you recommend?

Thankyou..

Comment: Use [this](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)